# How to save 3 objects from node.js to parse.com with relations

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform, relationship

I'm trying to use node.js (v0.10.28, mac os x) to save 3 objects to parse.com. The objects have relations to each other.

Here are the relations: 
[image: relations between data]

I configured the Classes using the data browser:

- Car (not being updated by the script)
  [image]
- Drives
  [image]
- Res
  [image]
- StaSto
  [image]

My goal is to understand Relations (yes, I read the documentation on relations on parse.com, but I can't apply it to this simple example). My script will

1. query for the car I want (only 1 in parse.com),
2. then it will create the objects for `Car`, `Drives`, `Res` and `StaSto
3. then it will relate the objects and put some fake values in them.
4. and finally, it will try to save them. Here is where the script fails with the error: `Failed to create new myRes, with error code: undefined`. `myDrive` gets created, even if it should be the last element to be created and the creation of `myRes` fails.

can anyone helps? Or is there other better way to do it?

Thanks.

Here is my script:

```
console.log("Starting");
// +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
// PARSE Classes!
// +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
var Parse = require('parse').Parse;
var parse_JSKey = "xxx";
var parse_AppKey = "xxx";
Parse.initialize(parse_AppKey, parse_JSKey);
// +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++



// +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
// PARSE Classes!
// +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
var Drives = Parse.Object.extend("Drives");
var StaSto = Parse.Object.extend("StaSto");
var Res = Parse.Object.extend("Res");
var Car = Parse.Object.extend("Car");
// +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++



// +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
// fake data
// +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
var myDriveData = {'distance':21, 'speed': 99};
var carID = "mrNQcPRNl4"; //already in parse.com!
var myStaSto_lat = 48.1333;
var myStaSto_lng = 11.5667;
// +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++



// +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
// insert into parse
// +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
//   --- query for the car
var carQuery = new Parse.Query(Car);
carQuery.get(carID, {
  success: function(result) {
    var thisCar = result;
//   --- create a new drive
    var myDrive = new Drives(); // created a new object, but empty
    myDrive.set('distance', myDriveData.distance);
    myDrive.set('speed', myDriveData.speed);
//   --- create a new StaSto
    var myStaSto = new StaSto();
    myStaSto.set('coord',new Parse.GeoPoint({latitude: myStaSto_lat, longitude: myStaSto_lng}));
    myStaSto.set('drive',myDrive);
//   --- create a new Res
    var myRes = new Res();
    myRes.set('drive',myDrive);
    myRes.set('car',thisCar);
    myRes.set('res',717);
    console.log(myRes);
//   --- ----> save them all
    myRes.save(null, {
      success: function(response) {
        // Execute any logic that should take place after the object is saved.
        console.log('saved myRes succesfully');
        myStaSto.save(null,{
          success: function(response){
            console.log('saved myStaSto succesfully');

            myDrive.save(null,{
              success: function(response){
                console.log('saved myDrive succesfully');

              },
              error: function(response,error){
                  console.log('Failed to create new myDrive, with error code: ' + error.description);
              }
            }); // end of myDrive.save

          },
          error: function(response,error){
              console.log('Failed to create new myStaSto, with error code: ' + error.description);
          }
        }); // end of myStaSto save
      },
      error: function(response, error) {
        // Execute any logic that should take place if the save fails.
        // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and description.
        console.log('Failed to create new myRes, with error code: ' + error.description);
      }
    }); // end of myRes.save
  },
  error: function(object, error) {
    console.log('error in car query: ' + error.code + " " + error.message);
  }
}); // end of car query.



// +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that my code was correct. The error comes because I set up the column as a relation in parse.com (see pictures).

I changed that to Pointer, and voila, it works just fine. I must admit that the JavaScript developer Guide of parse.com is a bit short on mentioning this.

[image]

Comment: The Parse JS guide is almost comically incomplete. Almost because it's lack of pragmatic examples is really horrible.

Answer (score 0):

dont see anything wrong with your code around the 'save.res. You might want to read up on [parse promises](http://blog.parse.com/2013/01/29/whats-so-great-about-javascript-promises/) tho...

try playing with it in a less complex form.

try to save 'res' with just one FK type relation and , say a straight value in 'res.drive'..

In the lucky chance that you get a good Save instead of 'undef' error then...

you can try switching one of your current relation types to a pointer and see if that works.

Comment: I tried before setting only 1 relation from `Res` to `Drives`, and that worked after saving `Res`. The object of `Drives` will be automatically saved too. but what I really need is to make this (`Res` to `Drives` and `Car`) and (`StaSto` to `Drives`).

Comment: Check built in class _Role.  Their are 2 relation fields in that class ( users , roles) both store an array in the relation. So use an array to wrap your relation Val's and see how that goes

Comment: `Parse.Role` is about access control. I don't know if it is what you meant? http://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Role.html

Comment: only mention that class as example where  there are 2 fields containing relations - each inside array.  I would suggest that you save 'Res' to get a reference and then try updating it in separate step with your relations.

Comment: you should also be able to make it work with 2 relation fields if that logical model is better.

Comment: See my answer below. The problem was not the code but the declaration of the relations in parse.com's data browser. Now I declared the relation columns as `Pointers`, and everything works as expected.